# How to cast a list of objects from realtime db to a list of strings?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

here's what my db looks like

here's the code

```
DatabaseReference refHistory = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("history/$uid");
var result = await refHistory.get();
for (var element in result.children) {
      ....
      var uris = element.child("imageUris").value;
      print('my data ${uris}');
      ....
    }
```

here's the output of the print
[image]

I want to turn my `uris`(which shows up like type Object?) into `List<String>`, but none of what I tried (cast to map and use toList(), or use List.castFrom) didn't work.

Please help me out, any response would be appreciated!

Comment: try `List<String> myData= List.from(uris)`

Comment: @MD Yeasin Sheikh I used `List<String> myData= List.from(uris as Iterable<String>);` (bc without Iterable it shows error) but still doesn't work